# compare records within same table

Tags: sql, sybase

I have  Student_Table with following structure.

```
 Student_Note  Table 
  student_id  seq_num  note 
  11212         1       firstnote
  11212         2       secondNote 
  11212         3       thirdNote
  21232         1       secondstudentnote1
  21232         2       secondstudentnote2
```

so on

I want   to get latest note (which has largest seq_num)   for  a particilar student.

I have tried following query

```
  select tn.note from Student_Note tn   JOIN Student_Note tn1
            ON (tn.student_id =tn1.student_id AND  tn.seq_num < tn1.seq_num)
             where tn.student_id=11212
```

it is giving more than one row. How to achieve aforementioned scenario ?

I forgot mention  that I am using above  query as subquery . As per sybase  TOP clause will not work in subquery.

P.S. I am using sybase.

Answer (score 0):

OK - changed as apparently cannot use TOP.........

```
select tn.note from Student_Note tn   
where tn.student_id=11212
and tn.seq_num = (SELECT MAX(seq_num) from Student_Note WHERE Student_Note.Student_Id = tn.Student_Id)
```

Comment: I am using in subquery so in sybase TOP will not work in subquery .

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select      substring(max(str(seq_num,10,'0') + note),11,len(note))
from        Student_Note 
where       student_id=11212
```